# Alter background-color of accepted answer box

Tags: css, google-chrome, stylish

I am trying to set the color of accepted-answer box on [Cross Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) exactly equal (or close) to Stack Overflow. I think SO's style is easier to visualize.

The problem is that I am not being able to change the color of the 'Normal distribution' that circumscribes the number of answers on the question. See picture below.

[image]

I have tried to hover the mouse over the format and inspect the element to visualize the part of the code that changes this feature, but I did not get it.

I am using Stylish on Chrome and what I have got so far is:

```
.answered-accepted {
    background-color: rgb(117, 132, 92) !important;
    color: #e1e818
}
```

How can one change that background color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was me, I'd just forget that "Normal distribution" graphic and set the whole background:

```
div.status.answered-accepted, div.status.answered-accepted strong {
    background: rgb(117, 132, 92) !important;
    color: #e1e818 !important;
}
```

---

But, if you  really want to change that graphic, do the following:

1. Download [the relevant sprite](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stats/img/sprites-extra.png).
2. Crop and edit the image:  [image: new graph sprite]
3. Upload the image to your server or [Base-64 encode](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/Base64Encode/default.aspx) it.
4. The new CSS:

   ```
   div.status.answered-accepted strong {
       background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,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) !important;
       color: #e1e818 !important;
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you very much. That is exactly what I needed. I just matched the code you provided with the one I already had.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the colour because it is an image

Comment: Sorry to unaccept your answer, but @Brock's one solved the problem. Just wanted to give you a justification. Anyway, thanks for your attention.